# TPI calculation by PDAL

Tags: las, point-cloud, pdal, code-review, tpi

Is there a convenient way to calculate the topographic position index by PDAL?

I have LAS file and what I do is iteratively for every point calculate the TPI. The coordinate information I take from *filters.info* and save it as .txt file. This procedure takes about 1826 hours. The goal is to speed up the TPI calculation.

Comment: Have you considered using the point cloud to create a raster layer (DEM) and calculating the TPI from the raster similar to: https://landscapearchaeology.org/2019/tpi/

Comment: For code review there is the [codereview.se] Stack Exchange.